# How to store Hashes in Lists in Redis?

Tags: node.js, redis

Redis is new for me and i wanted to store the Hashes in List in redis but i unable to do that and i get the error

```
node_redis: Deprecated: The RPUSH command contains a argument of type Object.
This is converted to "[object Object]" by using .toString() now and will return 
an error from v.3.0 on.
Please handle this in your code to make sure everything works as you intended it to.
```

This is my code:

```
let object ={
    name:'jhone doe',
    age:25
};
client.rpush(['key', object], function(err, reply) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(reply);
});
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Redis](https://redis.io/topics/data-types), store the string version of the object. Do it like this:

```
let obj={
    name:'jhone doe',
    age:25
};
client.rpush(['key', JSON.stringify(obj)], function(err, reply) {
   if (err){
       console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(reply);
});
```